# nginx rewrite url without causing redirect and proxy to backend app

Tags: regex, nginx, proxy, url-rewriting

I'm trying to achieve the below in nginx:

Hit nginx on `http://<nginx-host>:81/admin/metrics` and have nginx proxy it to `http://127.0.0.1:8001` with the `/admin/metrics` *rewritten* to `/metrics`. The actual proxied admin app would receive `http://127.0.0.1:8001/metrics`.

So, `http://<nginx-host>:81/admin/metrics` => `http://127.0.0.1:8001/metrics`, and *without* causing a `redirect`.

This is what I have so far:

```
#admin app
upstream admin_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    keepalive 16;
}

#host /admin paths on another port
server {
  listen 81;

  #pass everything to backend admin app that matches /admin/* with /admin/ removed
  location ~ /admin/ {
    limit_except GET HEAD POST PUT { }

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_pass http://admin_backend;

    rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /$1 last;
  }
}
```

This is not working. nginx is not proxying the request back to the `admin` app and keeps returning a `404`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted this question on the [nginx users forum](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,262583), and got a solution from `nanaya` (thank you!).

Basically, all I needed to do was replace `last` with `break` in the `rewrite` directive:

So,

```
rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /$1 last;
```

became

```
rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /$1 break;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### redirect api and files request to backend

```
location ~ /api/ {
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://server:8009;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
}
```